# How to get the selected value from textarea in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am working on an example to display values in the text area and below is the link of the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QgWKTRsC6TBeqbFf80fO?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

   <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
   <textarea ng-model="stringArray" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" 
   rows="10"> 
   </textarea>

  <div>
     {{stringArray}}
  </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

// Code goes here

```
 var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

 testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope)
 {
      $scope.stringArray =
      [
       "First String",
       "Second String",
       "Third String"
      ];
   });
```

Now i would like to know how to get the selected value from the test area.If i select First String value from text area i should see only the First String value in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [window.getSelection().toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection), this will give the selected text, Also note a separate $scope variable is used to display the text, because using `stringArray` will replace the original content.

In this case `ng-mouseup` event is used

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.stringArray = [
    "First String",
    "Second String",
    "Third String"
  ];


  $scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    $scope.selectedTextDisplay = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <textarea ng-mouseup='getSelectedText()' ng-model="stringArray" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" rows="10"></textarea>

  <div>
    {{selectedTextDisplay}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi brk Thank you.It worked.Any idea how to make it a single click while selecting the value?

Comment: Hi brk when i type something in text area my update function gets called for each letter.How to call the function only when i complete my typing.